# Why we used the firstWhereOrNull method in Flutter explain with Example?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why we used the firstWhereOrNull method in Flutter.?

I am learning IterableExtention in flutter and confused in firstWhereOrNull and others..

Answer (score 0):

if you use firstWhere , if the element not in the list/array it will throw error, to avoid that we use firstWhereOrNull which benefits is , if the element u r searching is not found in the list/array it will return null